# What are the needed permissions of the initiator of a Nintex workflow

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-on-prem, workflow-activity, nintex

I have 2 Sharepoint-lists `list_local` and `list_Global`.. The users, who are working on `list_local` are not allowed to see the `list_Global`, but at the same time the `list_Global` should include all items from the `list_local`. So I have created a Nintex Workflow in `list_local` to copy the newly created item to the `list_Global`.

Now what I need to know is, what are the minimum permissions do the users of `list_local` need, in order to be able to fire up the workflow successfully. Please note that the workflow starts automatically after creating an item.